# Regex match string starting with dollar sign and contains ( and no spaces or hyphen

Tags: php, regex

Trying to get a regex that matches

```
$hey()

$hey('hi')
```

But not:

```
$hey->hi()

$hey moretext()
```

Needs to start with a dollar sign and have a ( and no spaces or dashes.

My idea was:

```
^\$.*\[^- ]$
```

Basically trying to find all the variable functions in my PHP code base.

Comment: Are you always matching a whole string?  I ask because I am seeing `^` and `$` anchors in your pattern.  It is good that you gave us 4 examples, but we may need more context.  Also, what are you doing with the matches?  How strict should the validation be?  Must the first character after the dollar sign be a letter? might it be an underscore or a number?

Comment: Does this work for all of your use cases? https://3v4l.org/gueUp  We probably need more detail to confidently give advice.  Why are you doing this task in the first place?  Are you wanting to run this regex in your IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a built-in lexer that is better (more accurate) than any regexp:

```
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php $var; $bar("hi"); $tar->(123);');

foreach ($tokens as $index => $token)
{
    $token_next = $tokens[$index + 1] ?? null;

    if (is_array($token) and $token[0] === T_VARIABLE and $token_next === '(')
    {
        var_dump($token[1] . $token_next);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you are wrong about the pattern since these lines are valid PHP code:

1. `$var   ();`
2. `$var\n\n();`
3. `${'  aaaaaa'}\n\n();`
4. `${"  aaaaaa$bar->bbbbbb"}\n\n();`

Comment: This is a much more considered and polished answer versus your earlier one.  Why didn't you just edit that first post?  Now your deleted one is hanging around (for users with the privilege to view deleted posts).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

\w+ will match all valid variable names, ( and ) are required. Anything (or nothing) is allowed between the ().

`^\$\w+\(.*\)`